# The second screen with hdmi displays incorrect colors

Tags: multiple-monitors, 22.04, colors

When I connect a monitor by HDMI cable with my laptop a faced a problem with Color that not compatible with laptop screen.

Answer (score -1):

from setting color, remove all (second monitor profiles ) and add the same profile of your laptop. in my case the monitor name TCL , and my laptop ASUS TUF Gaming

```
Settings > Color > TCL SMART TV Monitor
```

then click on it and select all profile if it has.

then click `Add profile` then select your same laptop profile " in my case it " `ASUS TUF Gaming A15`